# How to deploy MSSQL DB on Linux server

Tags: linux

is there any possibility for deploying MSSQL on Linux Server. as i`m new to the servers and all, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can't. see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(SQL.90).aspx

Mainly the part

> Operating System Requirements (32-Bit) OR Operating System Requirements (64-Bit)